# How do you group a list of elements in to pairs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

How would I get it to:

```
l = [12, 34, 56, 78]
```

Comment: Hey if any of the answers helped you out, accept that one.

Answer (score 5):

Using `zip`, you can combine elements together.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> temp = list(zip(l[::2],l[1::2]))
# [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Now combine them using `list comprehension`.

```
>>> out = [a*10+b for a,b in temp]
>>> out
=> [12, 34, 56, 78]
```

Answer (score 2):

A crude method may be, but here you go -

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
[ int(str(l[a])+str(l[a+1])) for a in range(0,len(l),2) ]
```

1. `range(0,len(l),2) ]` is iterating over every other element

2. `l[a]` and `l[a+1]` are getting converted to `string`, concatenated
3. The output is getting casted back to `int`

Finally the whole logic is done in a list comprehension in a one-liner. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty spot-on answers, mine is similar, but here goes.
Either of these one-liners will work:

```
way1 = [first*10 + nxt for first, nxt in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])]
way2 = [int(str(first) + str(nxt)) for first, nxt in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])]
```

In general you can do this:

```
general_way = [elems for elems in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])]
print(general_way)
```

`[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]  # general_way`

For those reading and new to python:

1. `a_list[starting index: ending index: stepping]` --
   so l[::2] means start at index 0 and end including index -1, and go to every 2nd element from starting index.
2. `for elem1, elem2, ..., elemN in zip(iterable1, iterable2, ...., iterableN):` --
   zip() takes multiple iterables and picks one value from each at comparable indices and returns a tuple yielding generator.

It is recommended that all iterables be of equal length when using zip().

Answer (score 0):

## List comprehention

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> x = [int(str(l[a])+str(l[a+1])) for a in range(0,len(l),2)]
>>> x
[12, 34, 56, 78]
```